# Overriding Class property in child Class

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, typescript

I do have the following 2 base clases:

```
class BaseHelper {}

class BaseService{
  private model:BaseHelper;
}
```

Now I want to implement BaseHelper and BaseService for a specific use case and assign a instance to my property.

```
class MyHelper extends BaseHelper{}

class MyService extends BaseService {
  private model = new MyHelper();  
}
```

I tried to to that in various ways, but always get compile errors. Is that possible at all? And if so, what is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some fixes that might help. First, change the `model` accessor in your base service to `protected`. This will allow derived classes to use this class member:

```
class BaseService{
  protected model: BaseHelper;
}
```

Then instead of re-declare field in derived class, use the field from base class:

```
class MyService extends BaseService {
  model = new MyHelper();  // Here you are using model from base class
}
```